# ¿Cómo buscar si los elementos de un objeto existen en los elementos de un arreglo de objetos?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo unos datos como estos:

```
datos =[
    {
        "id": 16,
        "bloqueNombre": "Articulos",
        "url": "https://prueba.unl/ws/api/articulos/"
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "bloqueNombre": "Capacitacion",
        "url": "https://prueba.unl/ws/api/capacitacion/"
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "bloqueNombre": "GradoAcademico",
        "url": "https://prueba.unl/ws/api/grado-academico/"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "bloqueNombre": "Libros",
        "url": "https://prueba.unl/ws/api/libros/"
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "bloqueNombre": "Proyectos",
        "url": "https://prueba.unl/ws/api/proyectos/"
    }
];
```

También tengo un método donde recibo los valores que ingreso en un formulario:

````
  postServicios(form: NgForm) {
    console.log('FORMVALUELALA', form.value);

   //intento buscar si en ```datos``` existe lo que recibe del formulario, 
   //en este caso bloqueNombre
    const nombreBloqueServicio = this.datos.find(
      (objeto) => objeto.bloqueNombre === form.value.bloqueNombre
    );

    //intento buscar si en ```datos``` existe lo que recibe del formulario, 
   //en este caso url
    const urlBloqueServicio = this.datos.find(
      (objeto) => objeto.url === form.value.url
    );

    //intento que si el bloqueNombre o la url, cualquiera 
    //que sea ingresada me compare con ```datos``` si ya existe
    if (!nombreBloqueServicio || !urlBloqueServicio) {
      console.log('YAEXISTEN bloque o url');
    } else {
      console.log('NOEXISTEN');
    }
  }
````

Lo que intento hacer es que cuando un `bloqueNombre` y una `url` se ingresen en el formulario, me compare con los objetos que existen en`datos` y en caso de que se ingrese un `bloqueNombre` o `url` que ya existen me muestre en consola que ya existe `bloqueNombre` o la `url`. Por ejemplo si en el formulario se ingresa estos datos se obtiene este objeto:

```
{
  id: 16, 
  bloqueNombre: "Prueba", 
  url: "https://prueba.unl/ws/api/articulos/"
}
```

En este objeto que se obtiene del formulario la `url:https://prueba.unl/ws/api/articulos/` ya existe en uno de los objetos de `datos`, por lo tanto me gustaría que diga que ya existe.

En este caso:

```
{
  id: 17, 
  bloqueNombre: "Articulos", 
  url: "https://prueba.unl/ws/api/nuevaurl/"
}
```

En este caso `bloqueNombre:Articulos` ya existe en un objeto de `datos`. Lo que busco es que un elemento del objeto ingresado en el formulario, que ya exista en `datos` me muestre que ya existe cualquiera de los dos `bloqueNombre` o `url`.

Lo que he intentado en [estackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bh13dn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2FbloqueServicio.service.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en el condicional que te muestra por consola si existen o no. Tienes puesto:

```
if (!nombreBloqueServicio || !urlBloqueServicio) {
```

Y ahí le estás diciendo si no existe ningún elemento por nombre o no existe ninguno por URL. En verdad, lo que tú quieres decirle es si existe algún elemento por nombre o alguno por url, por lo que deberías poner ahí:

```
if (nombreBloqueServicio || urlBloqueServicio) {
```

Y si no necesitas diferenciar entre si es el nombre o la url lo que existen puedes hacer el `find` de una sola vez:

```
const bloqueServicio = this.datos.find(objeto => 
  objeto.bloqueNombre === form.value.bloqueNombre || objeto.url === form.value.url
);

if (bloqueServicio) {
  console.log('YAEXISTEN bloque o url');
} else {
  console.log('NOEXISTEN');
}
```

Espero te pueda servir